# Carga de imagen base64 en Angular

Tags: angular, base64

estoy cargando imagenes desde mi base de datos en angular, las imagenes están guardadas en base64 y las muestro perfectamente en ocasiones, pero no siempre es así, al poner la imagen en mi vista marca error de propiedad indefinida al parecer no carga tan rápido mi consulta como la vista de angular, hay alguna solución u otra manera de hacerlo?

```
this.mockDataService.getImages('externo').subscribe((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      if (res.message === 'true') {
        for (let index = 0; index < res.images.length; index++) {
          if (
            res.images[index].posicion === 'slider' &&
            res.images[index].lugar === 'externo'
          ) {
            this.imagesSliders.push(res.images[index]);
          }
          if (
            res.images[index].posicion === 'lateral' &&
            res.images[index].lugar === 'externo'
          ) {
            this.imagesLateral.push(res.images[index]);
          }
          if (
            res.images[index].posicion === 'central' &&
            res.images[index].lugar === 'externo'
          ) {
            this.imagesCentral.push(res.images[index]);
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

Así cargo las imagenes actualmente pero sin un resultado favorable.

Comment: hola te invito a que leas este [post](https://codeday.me/es/qa/20190114/102540.html) donde puede abrirte paso sobre que es lo que debes hacer. Por mi parte, te recomiendo que solo en tu base de datos almacenes la ruta de la imagen y dejes lo demás al servidor. En tu cliente solo haces el llamado a la imagen, así es mucho más fácil.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el post, es básicamente lo que hago pero al parecer mi error era al declarar las variables let, en cuanto a lo no guardarlas en la base de datos lo hago porque el sitio y el api están en distinto servidor, además de que 2 aplicaciones consumen esas imagenes.